# How to randomize select image in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a basic rock/paper/scissors app in swift 4 for my nano degree program. I have looked over some of the courses from the Udemy class I purchased but cannot find the correct way to randomize the image/outcome that I would like to occur when the user selects their choice. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[here is what I have to go off when a user makes their choice but obviously its the same outcome every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQs6e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Before your switch statement you could add a line such as:

```
selection = arc4random_uniform(3) //Randomly give you integer between 0-2
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed I was using a arc4random line before but I guess it just wasn't in the right place/written correctly thank you so much!